# trying to use WooCommerce item quantity as a variable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce in functions.php, I've created a function where I can control the price of a specific product through the function. The goal is to create a product whose price equals some multiple of the total number of items in the cart. The idea is that I want to offer an optional add-on fee that is based on the quantity of items ordered -- all the "extra fee" plugins etc. assume you want to have a mandatory fee, but in this case I need it to be optional, hence I've created it as a product and not a fee.

The function works fine using a variable as the price -- if I assign 10 to $num_of_items, the product correctly shows as costing $10. But when I try to make the $num_of_items equal to any approach to get the cart items quantity through WooCommerce, I get a "critical error" on the site.

The specific method of getting the cart items quantity

WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count()

seems fine; I made a shortcode to test returning the quantity on another page, and it was fine. I don't know why that works and this doesn't. Thanks for any pointers.

(Side note: this was just my first step with this project; what I ultimately need to do is exclude a certain category of product from the total item quantity, but I just want to get this working first.)

In this function, for the sake of efficiency, I'm treating the product as costing $1 per item ordered.

```
function return_custom_price($price, $product) {
    global $post, $blog_id;
    $num_of_items = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $foodware = 1397;
    if ($post_id == $foodware) {
    $price = $num_of_items;
    }
    return $price;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your fatal error is about, but I fear WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() only works on the frontend, while you're trying to alter the price of a product on both frontend + backend.

I prefer to use the "*woocommerce_get_price_html*" hook instead of "*woocommerce_get_price*", so that I only alter the "display" on the single product page and not the actual field value.

Then, I move to the Cart, and only then alter the price. The correct hook for altering cart item prices is "*woocommerce_before_calculate_totals*". Here's my first attempt at your solution:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'bbloomer_alter_price_display', 9999, 2 );
 
function bbloomer_alter_price_display( $price_html, $product ) {
    
    // ONLY ON FRONTEND
    if ( is_admin() ) return $price_html;
    
    // ONLY IF PRODUCT ID 1397
    if ( 1397 !== $product->get_id() ) return $price_html;
    
    // IF CART NOT EMPTY SET PRICE   
    if ( WC()->cart && WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) {
        $price_html = wc_price( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() * $product->get_price() );
    }
    
    return $price_html;
 
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'bbloomer_alter_price_cart', 9999 );
 
function bbloomer_alter_price_cart( $cart ) {
 
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;
 
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 ) return;
 
    // LOOP THROUGH CART ITEMS FIND PRODUCT 1397
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        if ( $cart_item['product_id'] == 1397 ) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( ( $cart->get_cart_contents_count() - $cart_item['quantity'] ) * $cart_item['data']->get_price() );
        }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Interesting -- at first glance that does seem to work, thank you! Trying to adjust your code for what it needs to do, I realize that starting with $1/item is not a good test because at some point a calculation needs to be done, because it won't actually be $1/item. Let's say it were $2/item -- where in the code would I want to make that calculation? I tried to do it in the second of the two chunks of code, but that wasn't showing a change on the front end.

Comment: Also, just curious what the best way would be to go about excluding a category when calculating the cart items totals?

Thanks for your help with this -- this is a much different approach than I was anticipating.

Comment: @cheshiredave I've edited the snippet so that it multiplies by the product price, give it a go. In regard to the other question, you need to study [WooCommerce conditional logic](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-conditional-logic-ultimate-php-guide/)